# Converting an ArrayList of Points to a byte array to store in a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, image, arraylist, arrays

I have part of an application which is used to save a users signature on a hand-held device. 
I have managed to do this by having an arraylist of "Lines" which contains an arraylist of "points".
I need to store this information in a SQL database. The only info I have seen to do this, is to use the image data type and pass it a byte array. There being the question. How would I do this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert this data into an image, some information (which point belongs to which line) is lost. If you want to keep this information, you should *serialize* your data.

*Decide on the format*: You could use something terribly verbose like XML...

```
<Line>
    <Point X="3" Y="4" />
    <Point X="3" Y="5" />
    ...
</Line>
<Line>
    <Point X="10" Y="10" />
    ...
</Line>
...
```

...or some custom text-based format:

```
3,4-3,5-...;10,10-...;...
```

Of course, you'll be most efficient storing the data in some kind of binary encoding.

If you use a text- (or XML-)based format, your serialization will yield a string which you can store in a `varchar(MAX)` or `text` field in SQL Server. If you decide on a binary encoding, the serialization will result in a byte array. For this, `varbinary(MAX)` or `image` is the data type of choice. Note that the name `image` might be misleading: This does *not* necessarily mean that your data is encoded as an "image" (jpeg, png, etc.).

*Implementation*: For XML and a standard binary encoding, .NET provides built-in functions. Here's an introduction and links to walkthroughs on MSDN:

- [Serialization (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)

If you decide on some custom text-based or custom binary encoding, you will need to code the serialization and deserialization parts yourself. If you want help with that, you need to provide some more information: How does your data structure look exactly? What data types are your X and Y coordinates?

Comment: I ended up doing it this way. Thanks Heinzi

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want some form of binary serialization; here is a working version using protobuf-net (note I changed `ArrayList` to `List<T>`):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;
[ProtoContract]
class Line
{
    private readonly List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public List<Point> Points { get { return points; } }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Point
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int X { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var lines = new List<Line> {
            new Line { Points = {
                   new Point { X = 1, Y = 2}
            }},
            new Line { Points = {
                   new Point { X = 3, Y = 4},
                   new Point { X = 5, Y = 6}
            }},
        };
        byte[] raw;
        // serialize
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, lines);
            raw = ms.ToArray();
        }
        List<Line> clone;
        // deserialize
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(raw))
        {
            clone = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Line>>(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you let the user create a bitmap-graphic by signing with a stylus?
Sounds perfectly reasonable to me to store this as an image.

[create bitmap from array](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e57f7731-c703-4c17-b1a2-32b155f9b745/)

Comment: I am trying to save it as an image. And thats the question. The only way I can see of saving it, is as a "image" data type, which requires a byte array. I dont have a byte array, I have a load of xy points

Comment: Ok, I thought you would start from a Bitmap and get the point list from the Bitmap. Well, when in doubt: trust Marc Gravell :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a black and white bitmap from your data and then convert your bitmap to PNG image using .NET library:

```
MemoryStream pngbuffer = new MemoryStream();
Bitmap.Save(pngbuffer,ImageFormat.Png)
```

And store it as a binary data. Most databases have a format for storing binary data: PostgreSQL bytea, MySQL and Oracle blob, MSSQL image etc.

Comment: Why not? This is a format which is free (as in freedom), well compressed, displayed by every sane program which can display images, lossless and fast. Storing images as uncomressed bitmaps is so nineties.